# docker images tagged with latest tag is not detecting latest image refreshes in docker repository

Tags: docker, docker-compose

docker image latest tag is not getting pulled on docker-compose pull.
we build the `latest,0.0.1` version of the tags when we build a docker image with new changes.

but we do a docker-compose up it doesn't pull the latest tag dynamically, not sure why docker-compose doesn't understand that the latest tag contains more changes. we are using dockerhub for our automated builds, what could be going wrong here

Answer (score 0):

> docker-compose up it doesn't pull the latest tag dynamically

Because `docker-compose up` doesn't download the image if it already exists in local cache, just like `docker run`. Execute `docker-compose pull` (just like `docker pull)` to pull the image.